# prevent extra click on customdialogbox

Tags: android, dialog

I have one customdialog box which will appear on clicking the row of listview.And the data will display on customdialogbox from web service.Now ,if by mistake if i click twice, the customdialog box open twice.My custom dialog box is in Async class and i have call it on `onPostexecute()`.

Every time i click on row of listview -it should called Async class in which customdialog box is there.

How to avoid to open it twice?

Please help.

I have checked some other condition but it is not working for me.

```
    public void showCustomDialog() {  // this is the dialog box i have created
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            final List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("Low");
            list.add("Normal");
            list.add("High");

            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customdialoguniversalappointment);
            final ListView listcustomuniversalappt=(ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.listcustomuniversalappt);

            LinearLayout layoutsubject=(LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.layoutsubject);
            LinearLayout layoutappt=(LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.layoutappt);
            Spinner spinnerappt=(Spinner)dialog.findViewById(R.id.permissionspinner);

            ImageView cancel=(ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.imgcancel);
            Button cancelappt=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btncancelappt);
            Button confirmappt=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnconfirmappt); 
            EditText subject=(EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtsubject);
                  subject.setText("Appointment"); 


                  TextView txtdateslot=(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtdateslot);
                txtdateslot.setText("Date:"+DoctorAppointmentAPTrequest.universalapt_date+" Time Slot:"+DoctorAppointmentAPTrequest.universalslot_time);      



            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinnerappt.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

                spinnerappt.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int arg2, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        int index = arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
                     selected_item=arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();



                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    } 
                });  

                 System.out.println("APTCustomRequestResponse.runcustomuniversalappdata="+run_custom_universal_apptdata());
            APTRequestCustomAdapter adap=new APTRequestCustomAdapter(context,run_custom_universal_apptdata());
                listcustomuniversalappt.setAdapter(adap);



            cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    System.out.println("hello");
                }
            });

            cancelappt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }  
            });
          //confirm appt
            confirmappt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(APT_CustomRequestResponse.radiostring.equals("checked")){
                        showdialogforconfirmappointment();  
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Please Select a Patient to book a Appointment",2000).show();
                    }

                } 
            });

            getsubject=subject.getText().toString();
            if(!dialog.isShowing()||dialog==null){//here i am checking condition where it should appear or not
            dialog.show();

            System.out.println(isMatch);
            }else{
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
```

and in `onPost` method i have called it:

```
 public class APT_CustomRequestResponse extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{   
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
               showCustomDialog();//here i am calling custom dialog box

   @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String hunt= GetAPT_RequestCustomdata();
        return hunt;
    }       

        }  
 }
```

This async class i am calling in other class where my actual listview is :

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
    APT_CustomRequestResponse APT=new APT_CustomRequestResponse(MainActivity.this);
            APT.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Use below provided code for reference toward solving this issue.

 // Keep this as member variable to the class
 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);

 // your new method model
 public void showCustomDialog() { 
     // Here check this
     if(dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()){
         // Decide if you want to display a new one, if yes then write below code first
         dialog.dismiss();
         dialog = null;

         // Display a new dialog code here
     }else{
         // Dialog is no visible, diaply it here
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of try to avoid twice call of `showCustomDialog()` method try to avoid start `AsyncTask` again if task is already running on ListView row click. you can do this using  [AsyncTask.Status](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.Status.html) :

```
 public boolean isfirsttimeclick=true;

    @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                        long arg3) {

      APT_CustomRequestResponse APT=new APT_CustomRequestResponse(MainActivity.this); 
      if(isfirsttimeclick || APT.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
           APT.execute();

      }else{
             /// show message to user already running
        }

    }
```

Comment: Now,i can't see the result,control is going only to else block

Comment: @abh22ishek :  you also need to use one flag to start AsyncTask time when user click on ListView row and make            `isfirsttimeclick=true;` in onPostExecute method

Answer (score 0):

You should not send a request to the server when item is clicked twice.

Either show a progress dialog in between while first request is sent that will prevent user from clicking at the list item again.

OR check in onItem click like @ρяσѕρєя K said just to add to that use following code define APT_CustomRequestResponse object outside of onItemClick and in your activity:

In activity:

```
APT_CustomRequestResponse APT=null;
```

onItemClick:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
if(MainActivity.this.APT==null||MainActivity.this.APT.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
   MainActivity.this.APT=new APT_CustomRequestResponse(MainActivity.this); 
   MainActivity.this.APT.execute();
}


}
```

**EDIT**

In you Async task create a boolean to know if execution is complete:

```
boolean finished=false;
```

And in post execute set it to true:

```
finished=true;
```

and finally do this in your onItemClick:

```
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                        long arg3) {
    if(MainActivity.this.APT==null||MainActivity.this.APT.finished){
       MainActivity.this.APT=new APT_CustomRequestResponse(MainActivity.this); 
       MainActivity.this.APT.execute();
    }


    }
```

Comment: don't you think condition is wrong,condition in which you are checking ,in that i am getting error

Comment: What is the error that u r getting?? Can u post the code that u r tring??